# Performing a right join in django

Tags: django, orm, right-join

Here are my models

```
class Student:
    user  = ForeignKey(User)
    department = IntegerField()
    semester = IntegerField()
    ...

class Attendance:
    student = ForeignKey(Student)
    subject = ForeignKey(Subject)
    month = IntegerField()
    year = IntergerField()
    present = IntegerField() 
    total = IntegerField()

students = Student.objects.filter(semester=semester)
```

How can I perform a right join between `Student` and `Attendance` models, so that I can get a 
queryset with all of the `students` and attendances` if exists for a student, else null?

The documentation mentions left joins but not right joins.

Comment: Do you mean to say fetch all students who have an attendance record?

Comment: no, fetch all students. fetch attendance for a student if it exists, else null.

Comment: well,, then it is a simple `Student.objects.select_related('attendance')` - unless I am missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use such query:

```
queryset = Student.objects.all().select_related('attendance_set')
student = queryset[0]
# all attendances for the student
attendances = student.attendance_set.all()
```

With [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) you `JOIN`'ing `Attendance` table. Django does not have explicit `join` ORM method, but it does `JOIN` internally when you call `select_related`. Resulting queryset will contain all `Student`'s with joined attendances, and when you will call `attencande_set.all()` on each student - no additional queries will be performed.
Check [the docs for `_set` feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

If you want to query only those students who has at least one attendance, you can use such query:

```
from django.models import Count
(Student.objects.all()
                .select_related('attendance_set')
                .annotate(n_attendances=Count('attendance_set'))
                .filter(n_attendances__gt=0))
```

Comment: Watch out as this won't work - you can't select_related on a related manager (`attendance_set`) and the field name will actually be `attendance` for the `Count`. You need to use `prefetch_related` instead: ```Student.objects.all().prefetch_related('attendance_set').annotate(n_attendances=Count('attendance')).filter(n_attendances__gt=0)```

Answer (score 12):

change left join for table subject

```
queryset.query.alias_map['subject'].join_type = "RIGHT OUTER JOIN"
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way is using `fk_set__isnull=false` as show below:

```
class Father(Model):
    name = ...

class Child(Model):
    father = ForeignKey('Father', on_delete=..., related_name='childs')

>>> fathers_with_childs = Father.objects.filter(childs__isnull=False).all()
```

this will gave you a query like:

`"SELECT * FROM father INNER JOIN child ON (father.id = child.father_id) WHERE child.id IS NOT NULL"`