# Performing a right join in django (take 2)

Tags: python, django, join, orm

With reference to [Performing a right join in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510177/performing-a-right-join-in-django) , when I try a similar approach (field slightly different):

```
class Student:
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    department = IntegerField()
    semester = IntegerField()

class Attendance:
    student_attending = ForeignKey(Student, related_name='attendee')
    subject = ForeignKey(Subject)
```

When I run this query:

```
queryset = Student.objects.all().select_related('attendance_set')
```

I get this response:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'attendance_set'.
```

What could trigger that warning and how do I get the 'join' to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer to that linked question is, quite simply, wrong -
 as a comment there notes.

`select_related` only works for forward relationships. For backwards ones, you need `prefetch_related`:

```
Student.objects.all().prefetch_related('attendance_set')
```

Note, this will do two separate queries.